# Getting the right file path from a maven resource folder - iText

Tags: java, maven, servlets, resources, itext

As I'm using a external font for iText, I need to load the font file from my maven resource folder (src/main/resources) but the iText API requires me to provide a file path instead the file itself.

So, I'm having problems while trying to use this code:

```
String arialUnicodeFontPath = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("arialuni.ttf").getPath();

BaseFont unicodeBaseFont =
        BaseFont.createFont(arialUnicodeFontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

I get this:

```
2016-08-18 09:17:12,667 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/pdfgen2].[controlServlet]] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet controlServlet threw exception: java.io.IOException: /content/pdfgen2.war/WEB-INF/classes/arialuni.ttf not found as file or resource.
    at com.itextpdf.text.io.RandomAccessSourceFactory.createByReadingToMemory(RandomAccessSourceFactory.java:248) [itextpdf-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at com.itextpdf.text.io.RandomAccessSourceFactory.createBestSource(RandomAccessSourceFactory.java:173) [itextpdf-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.<init>(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:148) [itextpdf-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.process(TrueTypeFont.java:641) [itextpdf-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFontUnicode.process(TrueTypeFontUnicode.java:121) [itextpdf-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFontUnicode.<init>(TrueTypeFontUnicode.java:98) [itextpdf-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:704) [itextpdf-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:622) [itextpdf-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:457) [itextpdf-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
```

Comment: Is `pdfgen2.war` the file which contains your application? is the file `arialuni.ttf ` located there?

Comment: Yes it is my application, the folder structure is as described and opening the war file itself the structure is:  WEB-INF/classes/arialuni.ttf

Comment: try to add a "/" before the filename

Comment: I have already tried it and it didn't make difference. Weird thing is when i deploy it using jbosstools, i mean, inside eclipse, it works, and it actually prints a different file path than when i deploy it manually building the war using maven and copying the war file into the jboss folder. For some reason the method gets 2 different file paths depending the way i deploy it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution to load the file by it's path the way i wanted but i used a workaround to get the itext font the way i needed with the follow code:

```
byte[] fontByte = IOUtils
    .toByteArray(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/fonts/arialuni.ttf"));
BaseFont unicodeBaseFont = BaseFont.createFont("arialuni.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,
    BaseFont.EMBEDDED, true, fontByte, null);
```